# Passing an object to another class?

Tags: c#, oop

I've recently been looking into constructors, Im currently trying to pass a object to another class file, The way im doing it is like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 objPls = new Class1();

        objPls.nameArray[0] = "jake";
        objPls.nameArray[1] = "tom";
        objPls.nameArray[2] = "mark";
        objPls.nameArray[3] = "ryan";

        Echodata form2 = new Echodata(objPls);
    }
}

class Class1
{
    public string[] nameArray = new string[3];
}

class Echodata
{
    public Class1 newobject = new Class1();

    public Echodata(Class1 temp)
    {
        this.newobject = temp;
    }

    // so now why cant i access newobject.namearray[0] for example?
}
```

Problem is i cant access the object to get into the array..

What methods of passing objects are there? I was told this is roughly a way to do it and have been experimenting for a while to no avail.

Comment: If a class contains no instance constructor declarations, a default instance constructor is automatically provided. That default constructor simply invokes the parameterless constructor of the direct base class. If the direct base class does not have an accessible parameterless instance constructor, a compile-time error occurs. If the class is abstract, then the declared accessibility for the default constructor is protected. Otherwise, the declared accessibility for the default constructor is public.

Comment: It always helps if you provide the **exact compiler error** along with a minimal repro case. And if there's no compiler error, explain what your sample input is, what your expected output is, and what the **actual** output is.

Comment: Your code above won't even compile, it will break at this line: `objPls.nameArray[3] = "ryan";` because the size of `nameArray` is 3 but you're trying to set the fourth element.

Comment: did you notice that you are getting an exception because nameArray size is 3 but you are referencing it with a size of 4 in your objPls.nameArray[3] = "ryan".  if you change your class1 to string[] nameArray = new string[4]  it should work

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what it is you cannot do. For example your code with this modification works, or at least compiles.

```
   class echodata
    {
        public Class1 newobject = new Class1();

        public echodata(Class1 temp)
        {
            this.newobject = temp;
        }

        // so now why cant i access newobject.namearray[0] for example?
        // What kind of access do you want?

        public void method1()
        {
            newobject.nameArray[0] = "Jerry";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue where your code will throw an error when trying to set the "ryan" string on the fourth index of the array. You initially set the array to be of length 3.

In your EchoData class you can access the nameArray object without an issue but you must be accessing it within a method or in the constructor. You cannot be manipulating it's content outside of these.

Keep in mind that within your EchoData class you will not see the values you set inside of your Main method.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell since you haven't included a complete, compilable sample, and you haven't explained exactly what "can't access" means (do you get an error? what is it?)

However, my guess is that you are attempting to access the passed in objects fields from the class level based on your code.

ie, you are trying to do this:

```
class Echodata
{
    public Class1 newobject; // you don't need to initialize this

    public Echodata(Class1 temp)
    {
        this.newobject = temp;
    }

    newobject.newArray[0] = "Can't do this at the class level";
}
```

You can only access nameArray from within a member method.

```
class Echodata
{
    public Class1 newobject; // you don't need to initialize this

    public Echodata(Class1 temp)
    {
        this.newobject = temp;
    }

    public void DoSOmething() {
        newobject.newArray[0] = "This works just fine";
    }
}
```